# A simple App Intent to open Settings Accounts

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, huawei-mobile-services

Smeone created for me app to open specific menu on android (Settings > Accounts (The menu where the accounts stored in device are shown (Google,whatsapp,telegram,...)

It works on Samsung S8+ but on Huawei Y5 2019 it doesnt work (It's very important for me to work on Huawei)

```
package com.androidaccounts.app

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        launchAccountScreen()
    }

    fun launchAccountScreen() {
        Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SYNC_SETTINGS).apply {
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            startActivity(this)
            finish()
        }
    }
}
```

Where is the problem? I need to run app on Huawei too

Thank you

Comment: any logs from Logcat? The code snippet works fine on my P30 Pro with EMUI 10.0.0.190.